# Expectation on product space

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that  $\mathbb{X}=\mathbb{X}_1\times \mathbb{X}_2$ and suppose that $ P$ is a probability measure on  $\mathbb{X}$ with marginals $ P_i$ on $\mathbb{X}_i, i=1,2$. Is it then true that every random variable $X$ on $\mathbb{X}$ such that $\mathbb{E}_P[X]$ is finite can be written as $X=X_1+X_2$, where $X_i$ are random variables on $\mathbb{X}_i, i=1,2$ and $\mathbb{E}_{P_1}[X_1]$ and $\mathbb{E}_{P_2}[X_2]$ are finite?

Comment: No, already every random variable on $\mathbb X$ cannot be written as the sum of some random variable on $\mathbb X_1$ and some random variable on $\mathbb X_2$. Try $\mathbb X_1=\mathbb X_2=[0,1]$ and $X$ the indicator function of the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks @Did . Is it at least true that the linear space spanned by $L^1(P_1)\cup L^1(P_2)$ is closed in $L^1(P)$?

Comment: What is $L^1(P_1)$ if $L^1(P_1)\subseteq L^1(P)$?

Comment: @Did All I can say is that $L^1(P_1)$ is a closed linear subspace of $L^1(P)$. I don't know whether I got you correctly.

Comment: No, functions in $L^1(P_1)$ are defined on $\mathbb X_1$, not on $\mathbb X$, hence none belongs to $L^1(P)$.

Comment: @Did When I look at functions $f(x_i)$ in $L^1(P_i)$, I view them as functions of $(x_1,x_2)$. In that sense $L^1(P_1),L^1(P_2)\subset L^1(P)$.

Comment: I guess, since the sigma-algebra on $\mathbb X$ is generated by the measurable sets $A\times \mathbb X_2$ and $\mathbb X_1\times B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (negative) answer was given by Did in a comment; here are some details. Consider $\mathbb X = [0,1]\times [0,1]$ with the standard measure. Let $\pi_1,\pi_2$ be as in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/819488/147263) to the follow-up question. Consider $F(x_1,x_2) = \chi_{\{x_1>x_2\}}$. Then $$\pi_1 F(x_1) = \int F(x_1,x_2)\,dx_2 = x_1$$
If  $F$ was decomposable as the sum of function of $x_1$ and function of $x_2$, the difference $F-\pi_1F$ would be a function of $x_2$ only. However, it is not.